# How to join tables with O2M and M2M relationship?

Tags: python, django-models

I have the following related data models

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField('assortment.Product', through='CartProduct')
    order = models.OneToOneField('Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='order_cart', null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('account.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_carts', blank=True, null=True)

class CartProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('assortment.Product', related_name='product_cartproducts', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', related_name='cart_cartproducts', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    count = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=1)

class Order(models.Model):
    pay_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My code below gives an error: invalid argument "products" in prefetch_related:

```
Order.objects.all().select_related('order_cart').prefetch_related('products')
```

How can I join all three models in one request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query builder continues with the original table (`Order`), thus you have to specify the fields relative to that or relative to the previously mentioned field. Try one of the following:

- `'order_cart__products'`
- `'order_cart__cart_cartproducts'`

(Notice the double underscore.)

Comment: Thank you, both options are working. But I can't access the CartProduct object fields.The command "obj. order_cart. cart_cartproducts. count" outputs " < the associated BaseManager method. _get_queryset_methods.<locals>.create_method.<locals>. manager_method from the < django. db.models. field. related_descriptors. create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.<locals>. RelatedManager object at 0x7f5c149b7700>>"

Comment: @s-klimov that expression is accessing a query (a prefetched collection) of `CartProduct`'s thus `count` is a method.

Comment: how do I access the model assortment.Product fields?

Comment: @s-klimov try just `.product` of objects in the previously mentioned collection of `CartProduct`'s.

Comment: obj.order_cart.cart_cartproducts.product -> 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'product'

Comment: @s-klimov `.cart_cartproducts` is a collection, you have multiple products in your cart. Try iterating that collection, you will get instances of `CartProduct`, like: `for cartproduct in obj. order_cart. cart_cartproducts: print(f"id = {cartproduct.product_id} count = {cartproduct.count}")`

Comment: everything was easier: obj.order_cart.cart_cartproducts.all()! Thank you very much, I wouldn't have figured it out without you!